# Asynchronous jQuery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-templates

I would like to be able to create jQuery templates that gets filled in by data fetched by some asynch queries, for this I need to refer back to elements I render within a template. I have come up with a solution using a generated class-name, which I use after rendering the template to insert the data, but this is a kludge. Is there a way to get a reference to the rendered element from within the template code? Here is the code I would like to get working:

```
<script>
function renderData(prduct_id, element){
 getProductData(product_id, function(data){
  $(e).empty();
  $("#product-info-tmpl").tmpl({"data":data}).appendTo($(element));
 }); 
}
</script>

<script id="product-info-loading-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
loading
//Here is where I'd need a reference to the rendered element
${renderData(product_id, this_element_when_rendered)}
</script>
```

Comment: When thinking more about this, maybe it is not possible tog get a reference to the stuff that will be rendered by the templete at compile-time, so a different approach is needed. I'm redoing it using html5 data-attributes instead, but if anybody has more input on this, go ahead and post answers.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help, so in your case something with $item, maybe $item.parent or something...

Copied somewhere from http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/

> The $item and $data Template Variables
>   The following variables are exposed to
>   expression evaluation within
>   templates:
>
> $: The jQuery object. $item: The
>   current template item - which allows
>   access to $item.data, $item.parent,
>   etc. as well as any user-defined
>   values or methods passed in with the
>   options map. $data: The current data
>   item (equivalent to $item.data). Note:
>   A template tag with content such as
>   {{each}}...{{/each}} may expose
>   additional variables to template
>   evaluation within the content. In the
>   case of {{each}}, for example, the
>   additional template variables $value
>   and $index are provided within the
>   content of the {{each}} tag.

Comment: Nope, this does not help, since the $item and $data variables refer to the template-internal stuff, not to the generated output of the template, which I would need to be able to add stuff to it afterwards.